# Prisma NOT equal to true, filtering incorrectly

Tags: postgresql, null, prisma

I'm running a prisma postgres filter query, as below. However when I add the NOT equal to filter, it ends up filtering everything and returning no results, without an error. What am I doing wrong? I have a variety of entries with both is_soundtrack false, true and null. So I should be getting some results. I also commented out another approach to using `NOT`, however this also doesn't work?

I'm wanting to show all results, where is_soundtrack does not equal true.

```
const songs = await this.db.song.findMany({
  where: {
    name: {
      contains: "test string,
    },
    // is_soundtrack: {
    //   not: true,
    // },
    NOT: {
      is_soundtrack: true,
    },
  },
  orderBy: {
    spotifyImg640: 'desc',
  }
})
```

Comment: the `isNot: true` filter might be useful https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#isnot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I'm wanting to show all results, where is_soundtrack does not equal true.

So you need:

```
is_soundtrack IS NOT TRUE
```

Or:

```
is_soundtrack IS DISTINCT FROM true
```

Or:

```
(is_soundtrack = false OR is_soundtrack IS NULL)
```

The current filter `NOT is_soundtrack = true` would only cover false, but exclude null values.

[Read the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html)

Comment: Answer is not prisma query, but postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Prisma converts `isNot: true` to `where column <> true` which does not work.

This is what I had to do:

```
await prisma.questions.findMany({
    where: { OR: [{ keepHidden: false }, { keepHidden: null }] }
})
```